# Can only "Save As" in Microsoft Word 2013

Tags: microsoft-word-2013

On any *.docx document, even newly created documents, I can't save, but only Save As. Trying to Save or Ctrl+S only brings up the save as dialog. Overwriting the original doesn't work because Word still has it open.

Update: Saving works correctly on *.doc files but not on *.docx

Comment: When it comes to newly created documents (not saved yet) it is normal you cannot save through CTRL+S. Did you do anything with Word or your computer before the problem started?

Comment: Is the document in read-only mode?

Comment: @lowak: I meant newly created as in created after this problem started

Comment: @c0dev: No, document is editable